# Spotfire column title colors

Tags: python, colors, crosstab, tibco, spotfire

Spotfire 5.5

Hi, I am looking for a way to color code or group columns together in a Spotfire cross-table. I have three categories (nearest, any, all) and three columns associated with each category. Is there a way I can visually group these columns with their corresponding category.

- Is there a way to change column heading color?
- Is there a way to put a border around the three column groups?
- Can I display their category above the three corresponding columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One can make a color according to category by using Properties->Color->Add Rule , where you can see many conditions to apply your visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 7.0.1.9 and there is still no customization on table headers - besides choosing the font. Using rules to color table values would be your best bet, but it does not apply to the headers themselves, so you're pretty much stuck.

I have seen this example of custom css styling for creating an export tool, but that requires a much complex approach (basically you'll reconstruct the whole analysis by html coding) and I'm not quite sure would allow for header customization... anyways here it is: http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tutorials/HowToCreateExportTool.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1.Is there a way to change column heading color?
Ans : You can change the color for column headers. Please find the script below
if($('#my-style').length){ // do nothing style sheet already exists } else { // add CSS to the body $('body').append($('

```
.sf-element-table-cell.sfc-column-header { background-color:#566573;color:white;text-align:right;}
```

.sf-element-table-cell.sfc-row { background-color:#F4F6F6;color:Black;text-align:right;}
       
', { id: 'my-style' })); }

2. Is there a way to put a border around the three column groups?

Ans : You can do this if you have this column as rows in one column. if not you can perform Unpivot and bring them into one column. then build a cross tab by taking column reference as the category (nearest, any, all) column.
3. Can I display their category above the three corresponding columns?
Ans : you will get category once you perform above operation.

Please let me know if you need any inputs.